# I can't change my own folders (newbie alert)

Tags: permissions, qbittorrent

Apologies in advance, complete noob here.

I have qbittorrent-nox installed (commandline/web torrent client). When I download a torrent, qbittorrent creates a folder containing the files from that torrent.

Problem is, the folder it creates is read only. I know I can change permissions manually using chmod to 777, but that is tedious work doing that for every new folder. How do I make sure that all folders automatically created are 777?

I changed settings in qbittorrent to 777 (and rebooted), but it still makes read only folders.

[output from ls -la](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdviT.jpg)

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the output of `ls -la` of one of the folders?

Comment: done! added the link

Comment: Please, instead of a screenshot, add textual output as text (formatted as code, click the (?)-symbol in the editor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run it as usual user like I did first:

```
$ qbittorrent-nox --webui-port=8088

******** Information ********
To control qBittorrent, access the Web UI at http://localhost:8088
The Web UI administrator user name is: admin
The Web UI administrator password is still the default one: adminadmin
This is a security risk, please consider changing your password from program preferences.
```

Than it creates folders with the same ownership with which it have been started.

If you run it with superuser privileges as a daemon:

```
$ sudo qbittorrent-nox --webui-port=8088 -d
```

Than it creates folders with root privileges.

Run it without `sudo`:

```
$ qbittorrent-nox --webui-port=8088 -d
```

I specified 8088 port because of 8080 is used on my system.

Note: To stop it, use `killall qbittorrent-nox` or `sudo killall qbittorrent-nox` if you've started it with root privileges

My `~/.config/qBittorrent/qBittorrent.conf` now:

```
[LegalNotice]
Accepted=true

[Network]
Cookies=@Invalid()

[Preferences]
WebUI\Address=*
WebUI\Port=8088
```

I could delete files inside of that folder. It was created with the next permissions:

```
14156195 drwxr-xr-x   2 user  user  4.0K Mar  4 15:22 'GraphicRiver - Cyber Poster Photoshop Action 25597014'
```

Comment: omg awesome! it works.. and even makes sense.. thank you so much